# gradle get System environment variables

Tags: android, gradle

On mac if i use this under gradle:

```
androidSdk ="$System.env.HOME"
```

it delivered an output: /Users/MyName/

and:

```
androidSdk ="$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
```

it delivered 'null'. Altough i've set the ANDROID_HOME Variable and if i checked unter console

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

it delivered the right path.

Have anyone ever set ANDROID_HOME or something like this on gradle

---

ADDED:

My problems is, why $System.env.ANDROID_HOME = null, when on terminal "echo $ANDROID_HOME" give the right path??

Comment: set android variable in .profile file

Comment: I've already set ANDROID_HOME on my .bash_profile. Testing it using echo delivered the right path.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal use:

```
set ANDROID_HOME=/my_current_way_to_sdk ; export ANDROID_HOME
```

THEN, you need to run Eclipse, Android Studio,  INSIDE that same terminal.  Do not exit, do not open another terminal, etc.  Unless you change your .profile to ALWAYS do the above line.

Or - create a shell script to do the above set/export, then immediately run whatever you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> set ANDROID_HOME=/my_current_way_to/sdk

You need to use the console for this.